# Collision with two fragment shaders at the same time

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

My intention was, that the less space an object takes up on the screen, the less bright the object should appear.

This is fragment shader `fs_1`

```
        #version 450 core                                          
        layout (binding = 3, offset = 0) uniform atomic_uint area; 

        void main(void) {                                          
            atomicCounterIncrement(area);                         
        }
```

That's the second fragment shader, `fs_2`

```
        #version 450 core                           
        layout (binding = 3) uniform area_block { 
            uint counter_value; 
        };                                         
        out vec4 color;                             
        layout(location = 4) uniform float max_area; 

        void main(void){                             
            float brightness = clamp(float(counter_value) / max_area, 0.0, 1.0);
            color = vec4(brightness, brightness, brightness, 1.0);        
        }
```

I then attached the shaders to the program object. Now, the problematic part comes. I wonder if that's even acceptable or a complete mess. I created a named buffer and then bound it to the `GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER`binding point. Then, I bound it to binding number 3. I reset the counter with zero. After that, my intention was to reuse the atomic counter buffer in the second fragment shader, so I bound it to the `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER` target. Last, I pass the maximum expected area to the second shader, in order to calculate the brightness.

```
    glUseProgram(program);
    GLuint buf;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buf);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, buf);        
    glBufferData(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 16 * sizeof(GLuint), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 3, buf);

    const GLuint zero = 0;
    glBufferSubData(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 2 * sizeof(GLuint), sizeof(GLuint), &zero);

    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 3, buf);

    glUniform1f(4, info.windowHeight * info.windowWidth);//max_area
```

Like so, it doesn't seem to work. I also somewhere need to insert `glColorMask`, I suppose. This, in order to turn off the output of the first fragment shader. Furthermore, I think, I have to do something with `glMemoryBarrier`. Or is that not necessary? Have I called the functions in the wrong order?

I found no real references to it in the internet, no sample code on how to accomplish that. I'd be thankful for any answers.

Edit:

In addition, I have got some error message which makes the problem obvious:

```
glLinkProgram failed to link a GLSL program with the following program info log: 'Fragment shader(s) failed to link.
Fragment link error: INVALID_OPERATION.
ERROR: 0:8: error(#248) Function already has a body: main
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I have very soon remarked that that might be the problem, that two fragment shaders have the `main`body. So how could I fix that? Could I leave both `main` bodies and instead create a second program object?

Comment: Can't you calculate the screen-space area of your triangles in the vertex shader or even on the CPU, and then divide by that? Even if you can get this design to work, it goes against the grain of what the GPU is good at and is unlikely to be very performant.

Comment: So the *brightness* is a function of the "size" of the object and the distance to the camera (depth)?

Comment: Objects that are further  away take less space, so thats right. It is described in the OpenGL SuperBible, so I want to try it that way. It's just the code which is not completely described in the book so I'll need to figure  it out on  my own.

Comment: @F.Leuthold Did you try to link 2 fragment shaders to 1 program **!?**

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, these shaders are supposed to be run in separate passes, so why do you try to put them into the same program!? Apart from that, it should probably be pointed out that this approach will count how many fragments are processed, not how many pixels are visible on screen.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, but I have changed that now, but it's still not working.

Comment: @F.Leuthold You are confusing everything! Start with an OpenGL tutorial from scratch! You can't *use* 2 shader programs at once or even mix it somehow. The 2nd shader program (`program1`) would need a vertex shader too. Possibly you can use the same shader object as for the 1st program (`vs`). You have to draw the geometry twice. 1st time when the program with `fs_1` is active and 2nd time when the program with `fs_2` is active.

Comment: I have  deleted the confusing part in my question. I see now that it made no sense. I'm still stuck with my problem, but always learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the design to work, eventually!

I've followed the great advices in the comments. To sum up: I created two program objects with the same vertex shader attached to them. After that, I called `program` (with fragment shader `fs_1`) as follows:

```
glUseProgram(program);      
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

For some reason, I didn't have to call `glMemoryBarrier` or `glColorMask`.

I then made the following calls in my render-loop:

```
virtual void render(double currentTime) {   
    glUseProgram(program1);     
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

There, I used the second program object, `program1` (with fragment shader `fs_2`). I suppose it works, because there needs to be a vertex shader in each program object, not just in one. I then drew the triangle the first time, without any color output, but just to calculate the area. I then drew it the second time, using the "counted area" to calculate the brightness of the triangle.

I also realised, that the shaders are only executed when  you issue a draw call.